# Android Is it possible to use more than one searchable.xml per activity?

Tags: android, search, searchview

I would like to use different *searchable.xml* files accessed from the same activity, in order to change the links to different data tables, while running the application.
The *AndroidManifest.xml* can reference only one searchable.xml file per activity.

Is it possible to change the name of the referenced *searchable.xml* file during the run time ?

Alternatively, is it possible to change the table reference encoded in the  `android:searchSuggestIntentData`  during the run time ?

My *searchable.xml* file contains the following reference to a specific table called SOWS1:

```
android:searchSuggestIntentData="content://com.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.SearchProvider/SOWS1"
```

I would like to change it to a different table or query (e.g. SOWS2) dynamically during the run time ?
See also the related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20214971/search-suggestions-from-different-tables-in-the-same-activity)